# Run AWS SAM Local on another port

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam-cli

I've been successful in running AWS SAM Local on my machine on port 3000 with this command:

```
sam local start-api
```

The documentation says there's a flag `-d` that runs the server in debug mode on a different port. I need to run this on port 8080. So I tried this:

```
sam local start-api -d 8080
```

And the server still starts up on 3000:

```
Mounting api.get_account (python3.6) at http://127.0.0.1:3000/account/{account_num} [GET]
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `-d` (`--debug-port`) option refers to the port that you would connect a debugger to, not the port that the application listens on.

So `sam local start-api -d 8080` translates to "Start the application on the default port, and allow me to connect a debugger to port 8080".

To have the application listen on a different port, use the `-p` (`--port`) option.

You can of course use both.  For example,

```
sam local start-api -p 8080 -d 5858
```

means "Start the application on port 8080, and allow me to connect a debugger on port 5858".